# Issues with running a form MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having some issues with running my form, I have very little code for my listbox and it was all working perfectly fine until I added a button to run a query, then it threw an error. I've tried remaking the form and the query but nothing seems to be working.

https://gyazo.com/b9b838240504bb90d441329f46c6c829

This is the error I'm getting and I have looked far and wide for a solution for it.

Any help would be much appresiated.

Thanks
ShavedCloaca

Answer (score 0):

It could be just me but your questions doesn't provide enough details. Anyway I will try to give you something just by looking at your question and screenshot.

The field "Price To pay today" is populating **#Name?**. It happens generally when the query which is supposed to populate the field is not correct. Could you please check your query behind that.

Or right click on the field and go to property and check if the name and label is unique for the field or not.

One more thing that comes to my mind is that it is possible that you defined the type of the field as numbers or something but when you are fetching values, it contains some other characters along with numbers like **&** or **.** . Have a look.

Please post details for a better solutions.

Thanks

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply, basicly the field that is populated by #Name? gets populated after the user clicks a selection in the listbox, and this was working fine, i have a few hidden fields to run some working out as its the eaasiest way i know how and im on a bit of a time constraint.   https://gyazo.com/94ddcb420a752711d4bc364fdcb2dc42

Comment: Can you post code of the event that gets triggered when you select any list item ?

Comment: Private Sub Combo102_Click()
Me.TxtOldReturn = Me.Combo102.Column(5)
Me.TxtIssue = Me.Combo102.Column(4)
Me.TxtOldPrice = Me.Combo102.Column(6)
End Sub


i changed to it a combobox to see if that would help and it threw up the same error

Comment: Debug the code. Put a breakpoint in the line highlited
 Me.TxtOldReturn = Me.Combo102.Column(5) 
Me.TxtIssue = Me.Combo102.Column(4) 
**Me.TxtOldPrice = Me.Combo102.Column(6)**

and check what is the value that is getting assigned to Me.TxtoldPrice

Comment: it seems to be throwing up the error before it even runs the code,i put break points on all lines

Comment: i'm assuming txtoldprice is the name of the textbox for "price to pay today"

Comment: Wow..okay. Try changing **Me** with the proper name of the form.

Comment: yeah it is, im just so close to finnishing this for my coursework and its driving me mad

Comment: What happens when you try to debug that function ? What error you getting while trying to debug ?

Comment: the same one that i got before
https://gyazo.com/5791cbafd05d9db4b906a3197d6add7b

Comment: nope ive tried both of those solutions and nothing worked.

Comment: It would have been much easier if somehow I could see your screen..anyway...when you add a button in your form. Like excel is there **ActiveX Control** and **Form Control** ? Or just  one set of controls ?

Comment: no now when i add a button is get this error [link](https://gyazo.com/384b3193b82c69d918d8e3e8bf2a42d8)

Comment: Do you have any such line in the code ? `Screen.ActiveForm`

Comment: hard to figure out. Give me 3-4 hours if you can, I will access to MSOFFICE and I will try your code and everything. Sounds good ?

Comment: yeah that sounds great.. thank you so much for helping me :)